# How to find mean and median number of links of neighboring nodes

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to work out how to identify both the mean and median number of links attached to neighboring nodes when iterating through nodes `A1` to `B5`.  Below I have an example matrix, given as `matrixlist`, it's visualization, given as `matrixvisualization` and the corresponding adjacency graph, `graph`:

```
matrixlist = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
   1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

matrixvisualization = MatrixForm[matrixlist, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
    "B4", "B5"}, {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
    "B4", "B5"}}]

graph = AdjacencyGraph[verticeLabel, matrixlist,  
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
  VertexSize -> .8,
  VertexStyle -> White]
```

I've included a picture of the graph to help with the explanation of what I'm trying to obtain.  I would like to figure out how to find the mean number of links off neighboring nodes for each of the nodes present in the graph.

For example, in the graph provided, node `A1` has two neighbors, `A2` and `B2`.  `A2` has a total of 4 links off of it and `B2` has two links.  Therefore, the mean number of links off neighboring nodes with respect to `A1`is 3.  Taking the same idea and applying it to the next node sequentially, `A2`, the mean number of links off neighboring nodes with respect to `A2` would be 3.25 (Loops are only counted as 1 additional link so `A1` has 3 links in total).  I would like to repeat this process for each node in the graph and then create a list which contains the averages.

`meannewlist = {3, 3.25 ...}`

Taking the same process above,  I'm also trying to find out the medium number of links off neighboring nodes for each node.  For example if we start at `A1`, the median number of neighboring links with respect to `A1` is 3 (coincidentally the same as its average number found above).  As mentioned above, I would like to list all the median values in a list:

```
 mediannewlist = {3, 3.25...}
```

Any insight as to how I might solve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** We can use `AdjacencyList` to define a function to apply an arbitrary function to an arbitrary property value of neighbors:

```
ClearAll[neighborPropertyMap]
neighborPropertyMap[foo_: Identity, property_: VertexDegree][g_] := 
 ReplaceAll[foo[{}] -> {}] @* foo @*
   Map[(property /. Identity -> (#2 &))[g, #] &] /@ AdjacencyList[g]
```

***Examples:***

```
simplegraph = SimpleGraph[graph, Options @ graph]
```

*List of neighbors' degrees:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[] @ simplegraph
```

> ```
> {{4, 2}, {2, 4, 4, 2}, {4, 4, 3}, {}, {4, 3, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 3}, {2, 4},
>  {}, {4, 4}, {3, 4, 4}}
> ```

*Mean of neighbor degrees:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[Mean] @ simplegraph
{3, 3, 11/3, {}, 3, 3, 3, {}, 4, 11/3}
```

*Variance of neighbor degrees:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[Variance] @ simplegraph
{2, 4/3, 1/3, {}, 2/3, 2/3, 2, {}, 0, 1/3}
```

*Median:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[Median] @ simplegraph
{3, 3, 4, {}, 3, 3, 3, {}, 4, 4}
```

*MinMax:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[MinMax] @ simplegraph
{{2, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {}, {4, 4}, {3, 
  4}}
```

*List of neighbors:*

```
neighborPropertyMap[Identity, Identity] @ simplegraph
{{"A2", "B2"}, {"A1", "A5", "B1", "B4"}, {"A5", "B1", 
  "B5"}, {}, {"A2", "A3", "B4", "B5"}, {"A2", "A3", "B2", 
  "B5"}, {"A1", "B1"}, {}, {"A2", "A5"}, {"A3", "A5", "B1"}}
```

*VertexWeight's of neighbors:*

```
SeedRandom[77]
simplegraph2 = SetProperty[simplegraph, VertexWeight -> {v_ :> RandomInteger[{1, 100}]}];

neighborPropertyMap[Identity, PropertyValue[{#, #2}, VertexWeight] &]@simplegraph2
```

> ```
> {{8, 88}, {1, 52, 63, 79}, {52, 63, 77}, {}, {8, 88, 79, 77}, 
>   {8, 88, 88, 77}, {1, 63}, {}, {8, 52}, {88, 52, 63}}
> ```

```
neighborPropertyMap[N@*Mean, PropertyValue[{#, #2}, VertexWeight] &]@simplegraph2
```

> ```
>  {48., 48.75, 64., {}, 63., 65.25, 32., {}, 30., 67.6667}
> ```

*VertexStyle's of neighbors:*

```
SeedRandom[123]
simplegraph3 = SetProperty[simplegraph, VertexStyle -> {v_ :> RandomColor[]}];

neighborPropertyMap[Identity, PropertyValue[{#, #2}, VertexStyle] &]@simplegraph3
```

[image]

```
neighborPropertyMap[Lighter@*Lighter, PropertyValue[{#, #2}, VertexStyle] &]@simplegraph3
```

[image]

```
neighborPropertyMap[Blend, PropertyValue[{#, #2}, VertexStyle] &]@simplegraph3
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Remove the self-loops from `graph`:

```
simplegraph = SimpleGraph[graph, Options @ graph]
```

[image]

Get an `Association` associating each vertex with its neighbors:

```
neighborsList =  AssociationThread[VertexList[simplegraph], 
  AdjacencyList[simplegraph]]
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> {"A2", "B2"}, "A2" -> {"A1", "A5", "B1", "B4"}, 
>   "A3" -> {"A5", "B1", "B5"}, "A4" -> {}, 
>   "A5" -> {"A2", "A3", "B4", "B5"}, "B1" -> {"A2", "A3", "B2", "B5"}, 
>   "B2" -> {"A1", "B1"}, "B3" -> {}, "B4" -> {"A2", "A5"}, 
>   "B5" -> {"A3", "A5", "B1"}|>
> ```

Map `VertexDegree` on `neighborsList` to get an `Association` linking each vertex to the list of vertex degrees of its neighbors:

```
neighborDegrees = Map[VertexDegree[simplegraph, #] &] /@ neighborsList
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> {4, 2}, "A2" -> {2, 4, 4, 2}, "A3" -> {4, 4, 3}, "A4" -> {},
>   "A5" -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, "B1" -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, "B2" -> {2, 4}, 
>   "B3" -> {}, "B4" -> {4, 4}, "B5" -> {3, 4, 4}|>
> ```

Alternatively, map `Length @* neighborsList` on `neighborsList` (number of neighbors of each neighbor):

```
Map[Length @* neighborsList] /@ neighborsList == neighborDegrees
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now map any function you like to the association values:

```
foo /@ neighborDegrees
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> foo[{4, 2}], "A2" -> foo[{2, 4, 4, 2}], 
>   "A3" -> foo[{4, 4, 3}], "A4" -> foo[{}], "A5" -> foo[{4, 3, 2, 3}], 
>   "B1" -> foo[{4, 3, 2, 3}], "B2" -> foo[{2, 4}], "B3" -> foo[{}], 
>   "B4" -> foo[{4, 4}], "B5" -> foo[{3, 4, 4}]|>
> ```

```
If[# === {}, {}, Median@#] & /@ neighborDegrees
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> 3, "A2" -> 3, "A3" -> 4, "A4" -> {}, "A5" -> 3, "B1" -> 3, 
>  "B2" -> 3, "B3" -> {}, "B4" -> 4, "B5" -> 4|>
> ```

```
Values @ %
```

> ```
>  {3, 3, 4, {}, 3, 3, 3, {}, 4, 4}
> ```

```
If[# === {}, {}, Mean@#] & /@ neighborDegrees
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> 3, "A2" -> 3, "A3" -> 11/3, "A4" -> {}, "A5" -> 3, 
>   "B1" -> 3, "B2" -> 3, "B3" -> {}, "B4" -> 4, "B5" -> 11/3|>
> ```

```
Values @ %
```

> ```
> {3, 3, 11/3, {}, 3, 3, 3, {}, 4, 11/3}
> ```

Comment: Above, you have a code for `VertexWeight's of neighbors`. How can I do the same for `EdgeWeight's of neighbors`?

Comment: I don't know OTTOMH how to use `neighborPropertyMap` to get  properties of incident edges.

Answer (score 2):

You can work directly with the input matrix

1. Construct a `SparseArray` from  `matrixlist`
2. Use `` SparseArray`SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal `` to remove the diagonal
3. Take the property `"AdjacencyLists"`
4. Use `MapIndexed` + `Association` to get an association associating each vertex index to the indices of adjacent vertices

```
nL = Association @
      MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &] @
       SparseArray`SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal[SparseArray @ matrixlist] @
       "AdjacencyLists"
```

> ```
>  <|1 -> {2, 7}, 2 -> {1, 5, 6, 9}, 3 -> {5, 6, 10}, 4 -> {}, 
>    5 -> {2, 3, 9, 10}, 6 -> {2, 3, 7, 10}, 7 -> {1, 6}, 8 -> {}, 
>    9 -> {2, 5}, 10 -> {3, 5, 6}|>
> ```

Map `Length @* nL` on `nL` (get the neighbor counts of neighbors):

```
nD = Map[Length @* nL] /@ nL
<|1 -> {4, 2}, 2 -> {2, 4, 4, 2}, 3 -> {4, 4, 3}, 4 -> {}, 
 5 -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, 6 -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, 7 -> {2, 4}, 8 -> {}, 
 9 -> {4, 4}, 10 -> {3, 4, 4}|>
```

Map any function you desire on `nD`:

```
foo /@ nD
```

> ```
> <|1 -> foo[{4, 2}], 2 -> foo[{2, 4, 4, 2}], 3 -> foo[{4, 4, 3}], 
>  4 -> foo[{}], 5 -> foo[{4, 3, 2, 3}], 6 -> foo[{4, 3, 2, 3}], 
>  7 -> foo[{2, 4}], 8 -> foo[{}], 9 -> foo[{4, 4}], 
>  10 -> foo[{3, 4, 4}]|>
> ```

```
Mean /@ nD /. Mean[{}] -> {}
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 11/3, 4 -> {}, 5 -> 3, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 3, 8 -> {},
>   9 -> 4, 10 -> 11/3|>
> ```

```
Median /@ nD /. Median[{}] -> {}
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> {}, 5 -> 3, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 3, 8 -> {}, 
>  9 -> 4, 10 -> 4|>
> ```

If you desire, you can replace key `i` with `verticeLabel[[i]]` in `nD`

```
nD2 = KeyMap[verticeLabel[[#]] &]@nD
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> {4, 2}, "A2" -> {2, 4, 4, 2}, "A3" -> {4, 4, 3}, "A4" -> {},
>   "A5" -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, "B1" -> {4, 3, 2, 3}, "B2" -> {2, 4}, 
>   "B3" -> {}, "B4" -> {4, 4}, "B5" -> {3, 4, 4}|>
> ```